# my code block-compiled program crashes when running a specific code

Tags: c, codeblocks

Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
menu()
{
    printf("%37s\n", "SATAY RESTAURANT");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Combo Type                 Item                     Price(RM)\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("    A        25 Chicken Satay + 25 Beef Satay         40.00\n");
    printf("    B        30 Chicken Satay + 20 Mutton Satay       52.00\n");
    printf("    C        10 Mutton Satay  + 40 Beef Satay         46.00\n");
    printf("  Add-On      1 Ketupat                                0.60\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
main()
{
    menu();
    int quantity, ketqn, counter;
    char combo;
    char ketupat;
    float total, protoprice, combp, ketp, ttket;
    float calculatePrice(combo);

    total = 0;
    combo = 1;

    printf("\nEnter combo type (A/B/C or X to end)       :",counter);
    scanf("\n%c,&combo");
    combo=toupper(combo);

    while(combo!='X')
    {
        printf("Enter quantity : ");
        scanf("\n%d",&quantity);
        combp=calculatePrice(combo);
        protoprice=quantity*combp;
        total+=protoprice;
        printf("Order price for Combo %c       : RM %.2f\n",combo,protoprice);
        counter = counter+1;
        printf("\nEnter combo type(A/B/C or X to end)       :",counter);
        scanf("\n%c",&combo);
        combo=toupper(combo);
    }
    printf("\nAdd-on ketupat (Y/N)  : ");
    scanf("\n%c",&ketupat);
    fflush(stdin);
    ketupat=toupper(ketupat);

    if (ketupat=='Y')
    {

        ketp=0.60;
        printf("\nEnter ketupat quantity    :");
        scanf("\n%d",&ketqn);
        ttket=ketp*ketqn;
        printf("\nOrder price for ketupat : RM%.2f",ttket);
        total+=ttket;
        printf("\nTotal order price : RM%.2f",total);
    }
    else
    {
        ketp=0.00;
        ttket=ketp*ketqn;
        printf("\nOrder price for ketupat : RM%.2f", ttket);
        total+=ttket;
        printf("\nTotal order price : RM%.2f", total);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
float calculatePrice(combo)
{
    float combp;

    if (combo=='A')
        combp=40.00;
        else if(combo=='B')
            combp=52.00;
        else if(combo=='C')
            combp=46.00;
        else
            combp=0.00;

    return combp;
}
```

I uses codeblocks to compile my C code. The problem is that when I run this code the .exe crashes.  But it doesn't display any error when I debug it. How does this happen? Is it because of my code or some other factor?

Comment: Your first`scanf` is wrong.

Comment: `scanf("\n%c,&combo")` --> `scanf("\n%c",&combo)`

Comment: `float calculatePrice(combo)` --> `float calculatePrice(char combo)` and you should have it above the `main`

Comment: owhhhh i see, but after i editted it,the debugger does display the error: invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'int')|. what does that mean?

Comment: for which line?

Comment: printf("\nEnter combo type (A/B/C or X to end)       :",counter);
    scanf("\n%c,"&combo);
    combo=toupper(combo);
the scanf line

Comment: as @lurker pointed out, remove the `\n`, also in the `printf` line before: the `counter` variable is not used

Comment: it still display the same.after i change it to scanf("%c,"&combo);

Comment: you got the comma in ",", which is wrong:  scanf("%c,"&combo); to  scanf("%c", &combo);

Comment: omggg IT WORKSSSS THANK YOU!!!! <3

Comment: Any call to `scanf` (E.g. `scanf("\n%d",&quantity);`) that fails to **check the return** is just asking for trouble and likely to invoke *Undefined Behavior* (or result in an infinite loop). Always **always** validate all inputs (especially user-input).

Comment: **[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is *not* a compiler**, but an IDE. It is running some compiler (perhaps [`gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org)). So your code is not compiled by CodeBlocks (but by the compiler that CodeBlocks runs)! Also, read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code. I have corrected them and commented them on the code itself. Go through it. This worked pretty will in `gcc`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void menu()                                                                     // function should have some return type.
{
    printf("%37s\n", "SATAY RESTAURANT");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Combo Type                 Item                     Price(RM)\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("    A        25 Chicken Satay + 25 Beef Satay         40.00\n");
    printf("    B        30 Chicken Satay + 20 Mutton Satay       52.00\n");
    printf("    C        10 Mutton Satay  + 40 Beef Satay         46.00\n");
    printf("  Add-On      1 Ketupat                                0.60\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
int main()                                                                    // function should have some return type.               
{
    menu();
    int quantity, ketqn, counter;
    char combo;
    char ketupat;
    float total, protoprice, combp, ketp, ttket;
    float calculatePrice(char combo);                   // should be char combo.

    total = 0;                                          
    counter =1;                         // no needed combo=0 , should be counter =1 ;

    printf("\nEnter combo type (A/B/C or X to end)      %d  :",counter);          //  no "%d" 
    scanf("\n%c",&combo);                                                        //scanf("\n%c,&combo");                                                                                                        
    combo=toupper(combo);

    while(combo!='X')
    {
        printf("Enter quantity : ");
        scanf("\n%d",&quantity);                                                      
        combp=calculatePrice(combo);
        protoprice=quantity*combp;
        total+=protoprice;
        printf("Order price for Combo %c       : RM %.2f",combo,protoprice);
        counter = counter+1;
        printf("\nEnter combo type(A/B/C or X to end)     %d  :",counter);         //  no "%d" 
        scanf("\n%c",&combo);                                                        
        combo=toupper(combo);
    }
    printf("\nAdd-on ketupat (Y/N)  : ");
    scanf("\n%c",&ketupat);                                                           
    fflush(stdin);
    ketupat=toupper(ketupat);

    if (ketupat=='Y')
    {

        ketp=0.60;
        printf("\nEnter ketupat quantity    :");
        scanf("\n%d",&ketqn);                                                        
        ttket=ketp*ketqn;
        printf("\nOrder price for ketupat : RM%.2f",ttket);
        total+=ttket;
        printf("\nTotal order price : RM%.2f",total);
    }
    else
    {
        ketp=0.00;
        ttket=ketp*ketqn;
        printf("\nOrder price for ketupat : RM%.2f", ttket);
        total+=ttket;
        printf("\nTotal order price : RM%.2f", total);
    }
    //getch();                                                                   getch() is not a part of gcc. you may use getchar().
    return 0;
}
float calculatePrice(char combo)                                                    // type of combo should be defined here.
{
    float combp;

    if (combo=='A')
        combp=40.00;
        else if(combo=='B')
            combp=52.00;
        else if(combo=='C')
            combp=46.00;
        else
            combp=0.00;

    return combp;
}
```

Comment: There are more bugs to fix: move `float calculatePrice(char combo);` outside of the body of `main`, remove `fflush(stdin)` that has undefined behavior, test the return values of `scanf()`... not to mention logic errors.